# streamlit width autoadjusment

Tags: python, plot, dashboard, streamlit

How can I change the size of the main interface (where most of the dashboard is)?

I made a dashboard using Streamlit. This dashboard has a sidebar and the main interface. I realized I need to hide the sidebar if I want to see the entire dashboard. Of course I can scroll right if I want to see the entire main interface, but this is exactly what I want to avoid.
How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try options here:https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/utilities/st.set_page_config